# Storing social profiles in a database field Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

In an application I'm building I have a migration for a Profiles table as defined below:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_username');
            $table->mediumText('skills')->nullable();
            $table->mediumText('background')->nullable();
            $table->string('socialProfiles')->nullable();
            $table->string('displayPicture')->default('../../assets/images/user_pic.jpg');
            $table->string('mangedByUsername')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('changesPending')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

One of these fields is called `socialProfiles`. In this field, I'm thinking of having an array similar to the following:

```
$profile['Twitter'] = "URL";
$profile['Twitter'] = "URL";
```

Within the field, if possible?

So that when I initially create the profile, it initialises the array and then when a user types a URL in the corresponding text box and hits save, the URL is put in the correct position in the array.

Alternatively, I was going to use a social profiles table and reference the user id but surely this is overkill?

If anyone has approached this before, how did you solve it?

Comment: Do it with another table. It won't kill the performance just a little overhead which is bearable with insert operation. But when you do with field you had to make them comma separated values. then you had to check which value is for which social profile through domain. so go with the table

Comment: Could use a [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

Answer (score 2):

Add another Model SocialProfiles.

Then in your Profiles define the relationship

$this->hasMany(SocialProfile::class);

That's the best you can have so far ..

Comment: In this scenario would I not then have to define what profiles I want? Or could I just have profile_id, the url and the name of the network?